# Assign rights to create new version of an item if a user does not have write access

Tags: workflow, user-management, permissions

I have a basic approval workflow set up with three states (Draft, For Approval and Published), and two basic user types that can work on an item in this workflow (Author and Editor).

- An author can write to an item while it is in the "Draft" state and can send it for approval, but can't publish it.
- An editor can write to an item in any state and publish it as they see fit.

I want to use versions to allow authors to edit an already published page without affecting it. However, once an item is in the "Published" state, an author can't edit it any more due to them not having the "Workflow State Write" access right. This seemingly disables the "Add Version" ribbon item from the "Versions" ribbon strip.

Is there are way to give the author access rights to add a new version to an item which they do not have write permissions on (as in the above scenario) out of the box? I have various solutions how to set this up with code, such as creating a new ribbon button with a custom command (e.g. with a command defined as `item:AddVersionSecurityDisabled` that would disable the security before adding a new version for the item), but wondered if I'm missing a more standard way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, no. You will need a custom workflow action that will be wrapped in a SecurityDisabler() so the user can create the new version.

Comment: I have tried this but because an "Author" does not have the "Workflow State Write" access enabled on an item in the "Published" state, the workflow actions in the review tab are not displayed, even if I give the "Author" permissions to execute a particular command. If you are suggesting I create an automatic action beneath the "Published" state that will create a new item when it enters this state, I am trying to avoid automatically create a new version, so ideally would need something where a user has to explicitly create a new version.

Comment: Creating a new version is at the heart og how the Sitecore workflow works. So the item version 1 is in the web DB, version 2 is going through the workflow. You can't keep an item out of the web DB if you don't use versioning.